# Multi column distinct in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, distinct, group-by

```
| one | two |
-------------
| A   | 1   |
| A   | 2   |
| B   | 1   |
| B   | 3   |
| C   | 1   |
| C   | 4   |
```

I would like to get no repeats in any column in a query, so the standard 
`SELECT DISTINCT one,two FROM table;`
or `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY one,two;` doesn't quite work, because it looks for distinct in all rows, which in this case would return all 6 rows.

Ideally, I am looking for:

```
| one | two |
-------------
| A   | 1   |
| B   | 3   |
| C   | 4   |
```

In PHP (etc.), I would just do this with an array for each column, and if any column has been used before then skip the row.  I am not sure how to implement that in MySQL, though.

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY one) GROUP BY two`- almost works. but because the outer query doesn't see all the alternatives, it will miss valid options, i.e. the inner will collapse to A,B,C but could well pick **all** 1s for column two, which would mean the second GROUP BY would then collapse it own to 1 row!

I know the order of duplication checking will have an effect on the exact rows returned -- not worried about that -- I just want a good cross section of rows with minimal similar rows.

Comment: Explain your query rule. If there is 2 rows with the same `one` field, which one you want to have in the output ?

Comment: In your example you selected `A - 1` which is the first match, but in the other two you chose the second matches. Can you solidify your choice to one or the other?

Comment: In addition to Clement's question - what happens if 'C' in column one occurs only with values in column two that have already occured with 'A' and 'B' ?

Comment: Exacltly, solidify (funny translation of this sentence in French ^^)

Comment: It doesnt matter which actual rows are returned - hence my closing comment. The ones choosen in the example are just because I cycled though them in the order presented, if the rows where in a different order then might get different results. - Thats fine for my use case. 

@quosoo - then no C rows would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Well as it turns out I found an answer ;)

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 ENGINE HEAP SELECT * FROM table;`

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE (one), ADD UNIQUE (two);`

`SELECT * FROM table2;`

The IGNORE in the alter table is important, as it simply discards any duplicate rows based on the unique indexe**s**.

(not sure why didn't think of this before - as used it to good effect in solving "order before group by" style queries!)

Comment: or course in the real query have a WHERE and ORDER BY on the initial select, which makes it useful. Experimenting with different order by's, RAND() works well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in SQL: you can have six rows (every unique tuple), five rows (every first use of each column value) or one row (every first use of each value in each column which appears in both columns).

The reason you're having such a difficult time explaining what you want is that it's based on a human judgement call.  You won't be able to do this in SQL until you're able to describe it qualitatively in English, and what you want isn't qualitative, it's procedural.

There are a bunch of ways to approximate it, such as grouping by the lesser column then sorting by match count inverse, but they're all exploitable.

Until you can give an unambiguous, logic driven criterion for selection, this will not succeed.  Saying "minimal" doesn't count until you define minimal, and the minimal you appear to want requires procedural aggregate behvaior, which you cannot get in MySQL.

Comment: Probably the closest you'll get which doesn't incorrectly exclude rows is 

select distinct * from (select * from foo group by one) as l union all (select * from foo group by two) as r;

Comment: Thanks for the reply, admit don't understand the difference between qualitative and procedural - will attempt to read up on those terms...